# How to get plugin activate URL to use URL vars?

Tags: plugin-development

I need to get specific URL vars from the string of the **plugin activate link** when in plugins list view.

`/wp-admin/plugins.php?action=activate&plugin=move-blocks%2Fmove-blocks.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=6c106fb280`

```
add_action('admin_init', function() 
{
  if( $_GET['action'] == 'activate' && $_GET['plugin'] == 'move-blocks/move-blocks.php' ) {
    copy($src, $dest);
  }
}
```

When I run `$_GET` I do not see the query string as shown in the activate link. Apparently it's being processed by an AJAX function.

How can I get the literal activate URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out getting the URL on activation is not likely through the standard `$_GET` so WP has hooks for that.

#### Plugin Activation

I need to check for back up files stored in `wp-content` root, if they were created previously during de-activation or update, and copy to the plugin's folder.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, function() 
{
  add_option('move_blocks_activated','move-blocks');

  if( file_exists(WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/moveblocktmp/override.ini') ) {
    copy(WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/moveblocktmp/override.ini', MYPLGPATH.'/msg/override.ini');
  }
}
```

#### Plugin De-Activation

Action when the plugin `Deactivate` link is processed. This works during plugin update to store user created files while the plugin is deleted and replaced.

```
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, function() 
{
  add_option('move_blocks_deactivated','move-blocks');
  // create backup directory
  if( !file_exists(WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/moveblocktmp') ) {
    mkdir(WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/moveblocktmp',0755);
  }

  // copy files for backup
  if( file_exists(MYPLGPATH.'/msg/override.ini') ) {
    copy(MYPLGPATH.'/msg/override.ini', WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/moveblocktmp/override.ini');
  }
}
```

#### Action After Previous Processes

```
add_action('admin_init', function() 
{
  // delete the previously created DB option row
  if( !is_null(get_option('move_blocks_activated')) ) {
    delete_option('move_blocks_activated');
  }
  if( !is_null(get_option('move_blocks_deactivated')) ) {
    delete_option('move_blocks_deactivated');
  }
            
});
```

#### On Plugin Delete

Using the `uninstall.php` method in the plugin's root.

```
<?php

if( !defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN') ) {
  die;
}

// delete the backup directory
if( file_exists(WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/moveblocktmp') )
  rmdir(WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/moveblocktmp');
  // rmdir() will not delete a directory with files. I use a recursive function.
```